# Cannot access variable from another viewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have one viewController called "setTimeViewController". I have another view controller called "setEventViewController." users tap a row in a table in setTimeViewController and are sent to setEventViewController that only contains a UIPickerView and a save button. When the user taps the save button, it takes them back to setTimeViewController.

I want the value that is chosen in that picker from setEventViewController to be able to be accessed from setTimeViewController but is returning (null) to me. I have declared a NSString *theVariable in .h setEventViewController which is the variable I am trying to retrieve from the other view controller and retained its property but it is still null.

I have done a test (NSLog the variable) from viewDidDisappear in setEventViewController to see if it is null when the view is disappearing but it works as it should.

Here is my code, if anyone can help me I would forever be grateful. Thank you!

**setEventViewController.m**

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
  didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

theVariable= [currentItemsInPicker objectAtIndex:row];  
//[theVariable retain]; //Tried this as well but did not work
} 

-(IBAction) Save
{
//simply dismisses the view controller back to setTimeViewController. Have also tried to   set another NSString equal to theVariable but this did not work.
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**setTimeViewController**

```
 -(void) retrieveTheEvent
 {
  setEventViewController *eventViewController= [[setEventViewController alloc] init];
  NSString *testString= eventViewController.theVariable;

  NSLog (@"the event is %@", testString); //shows null
  }
```

Comment: Is it showing right value in setEventViewController.m? You can't do like this . Because value of variable cannot persist in another class.

Comment: @Alex G: Please check my answer and let me know if i can help anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allocating different object of setEventViewController in retrieveTheEvent if I am not wrong. You are facing this problem because this newly allocated object is different than you have pushed.

Instead of use the same object that you have push to navigation controller.

One solution:
Create global object your setEventViewController(i.e. I mean create iVar for it) and use same reference to push view controller in didSelectRow. And use same iVar for accessing your theVariable.

Add below code in setTimeViewController.h

```
setEventViewController *eventViewController;
```

Please also create property for it.

Now in setTimeViewController.m
Now use existing reference of setEventViewController to push view controller. like

```
eventViewController= [[setEventViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: eventViewController animated:YES];
```

Change this method
`-(void)retrieveTheEvent
 {
       NSString *testString= eventViewController.theVariable;
       NSLog (@"the event is %@", testString); //shows null
  }`

Comment: But doesn't setEventViewController *eventViewController= [[setEventViewController alloc] init]; give me the right to call any variable from that class? Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

Adding another solution to Armaan's list.

Create a delegate in setEventViewController.m and pass "theVariable" to setTimeViewController.m before calling

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Can you provide example please? sorry I am new to this. And doesn't setEventViewController *eventViewController= [[setEventViewController alloc] init]; give me the right to call any variable from that class? Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

I'm giving an example.

**setEventViewController.h**

```
@protocol setEventViewControllerDelegate;

@interface setEventViewController : UIViewController 
{
    NSString* theVariable;
    id<setEventViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}    
@end

@protocol setEventViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>    
@optional    
-(void)theVariableChanged:(NSString*)theNewValue;
@end
```

**setEventViewController.m**

@synthesize delegate;

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
  didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{    
    theVariable= [currentItemsInPicker objectAtIndex:row];

    // this is where the new value is passed to setTimeViewController
    if(delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(theVariableChanged)])
    {
        [delegate theVariableChanged:theVariable];
    }
} 

-(IBAction) Save
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    // very important
    self.delegate = nil;
}
```

**setTimeViewController.h**

```
#import "setEventViewController.h"

@interface setTimeViewController : UIViewController <setEventViewControllerDelegate>
{
// your members
}
@end
```

**setTimeViewController.m**

```
-(void)openSetEventView
{
    setEventViewController *eventViewController= [[setEventViewController alloc] init];

    // set the delegate
    eventViewController.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: eventViewController animated:YES];
    [eventViewController release];
}

// get the new value here
-(void)theVariableChanged:(NSString*)theNewValue
{
      NSLog (@"the event is %@", theNewValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out Singletons,

They can be your best friend when doing something like this.

[Singletons link here](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all different suggestion to pass NSString from one viewController to the other, including customer initialise method, and change the property to strong, retain, non of them work for me.

At last  singleton to share the data across the project fixed the problem. http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Thanks @David Evans